# How to get all populor Places having highest rating From google places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to get all populor places from google places API sorted ascending order having Highest rating. (nearbysearch of houston U.S lat = 29.760193 , lng =  -95.36939)
I tried this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=29.760193,-95.36939&rankby=prominence%20&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSydfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdgdfgcDBuNWG4


note: rankby=prominence
```

but it gives out put like this

```
 {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
 }
```

but it gives me valid out when `rankby=distance`

where Im doing wrong.

I want all populor places having highest rating first.

Comment: are you sure you have a correct key?

Comment: Yes. its giving me the correct out put when I request rankby=distance.

Comment: can you also send and post yours log cat please

Comment: @QadirHussain have you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well,For getting popular places you will call below api.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?keyword=coffee&location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&sensor=false&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[For more detail you can refer this link.](https://developers.google.com/places/training/additional-places-features)

Comment: with his key in this given link it is still the same problem https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?keyword=coffee&location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&sensor=false&key=AIzaSydfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdgdfgcDBuNWG4

Comment: I think he should send his logs and also need to check api key

Comment: Here in my question i have pasted a dummy key. I know its not a key problem.

Comment: @Yogendra. Yes your call is working for me but I want the all populor places having highest ratings. Whats the gaurentee that your url is returning me the valid results

Comment: @Quadir its all valid places because you can get it from google site. https://developers.google.com/places/training/additional-places-features

Comment: For ranking you can call this api. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json
  ?types=cafe
  &rankby=distance
  &location=37.787930,-122.4074990
  &sensor=false
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY